# I can't remember the title? Post-apocalyptic- Teens run away from cave cult in the desert to the city?

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

So I was watching TV in the mid 2000s and there was a post apocalypse movie/mini series/ TV movie maybe even TV show. I watched a little bit but I was babysitting and it was too mature for the little ones. I want to know if anyone can help me find it. I have looked for a while but I can't seem to find anything.

I'm thinking it was made in the 90s? maybe early 2000s, potentially 80s, maybe even 70s?
It was English, Live action, and on cable TV in Canada.

It was in a post apocalyptic future where a small society lived in a cave in the dessert. The society had young girls marry older men who were leaders. A teen boy tries to protect a teen girl from having to marry the old man/sleep with him and they tie him to a post in the sun after beating him up. Then the girl saves him and they run away together. They end up in the remains of a large city with all the skyscrapers falling apart. There they meet up with two other characters that are very different from the religious society they were from. I think they go to some type of hot spring?

I realize this isn't much to go on.

Comment: Was there a dog sidekick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Teenage Cavemen?](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/teenage_caveman_2002/)

> In a post-apocalyptic Neanderthal-style future world, teenage tribal leader David (Andrew Keegan) kills his Shaman father (Paul Hipp) for trying to have sex with his girlfriend, Sarah (Tara Subkoff). Because his father is this big spiritual leader, David is publicly punished and left for dead. However, his attractive band of teenage malcontents rescues him before the whole gang is swept up in a nuclear storm. They end up in the conveniently stylish 20th century dwelling of uninhibited Neil (Richard Hillman) and sexed-up Judith (Tiffany Limos)

Comment: Yes! That was it! I just finished watching it! It is such a strange movie.Thanks for the help!